# How to do formatting of expressions?

Tags: discussion, markdown

I'm having little bit trouble understanding the formatting of stackoverflow. Suppose I've an expression 2^n. How can I write in proper format.

Comment: 2<sup>n</sup> will do it. But note that ^ is XOR in many languages. Best way to discover is to click `edit` on a post with special format tricks.

Comment: @Bathsheba Where Can I get all formatting tricks.

Comment: @Atinesh: [Check out this](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for a start, some sections contain links to additional inforamtion. I didn't see anything about `<sup>` though, so I don't think it is **all** posibilities

Comment: @musefan it's part of the allowed HTML tags, documented [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1777/152859).

Answer (score 4):

write 2 and then use `<sup>`tag like this:

```
2<sup>n</sup>
```

2<sup>n</sup>